# hadoop startup errors: datanode, tasktracker won't start and data replication error

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to install Hadoop 1.2.1 on a (test) cluster of 5 machines with one node serving as JobTracker, NameNode and Secondary NameNode. Rest of the 4 machines are slaves.

There are two issues.

1) In the master's conf/masters and conf/slaves files, I provided the IP addresses of master and slaves respectively. On the slaves, masters file is empty and slaves file contains its own IP.

When starting up hadoop (bin/start-all.sh), TaskTracker and DataNode don't start.  I put in the host names of these machines in /etc/hosts file and tried putting in their hostnames in masters and slaves files as well. This doesn't make any difference -- TaskTracker and DataNode don't start.

While starting up hadoop services, I get a message that TaskTracker and DataNode logs have been written. But strangely, I don't find them in that location. Following are the messages I get

> 10.6.80.4: starting datanode, logging to /home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu-datanode-dsparq-instance4.out
>
> 10.6.80.2: starting tasktracker, logging to /home/ubuntu/hadoop-1.2.1/libexec/../logs/hadoop-ubuntu-tasktracker-dsparq-instance2.out

2) In the JobTracker/NameNode log, following exception is listed multiple times.

> error: java.io.IOException: File <> could only be replicated to 0
>   nodes, instead of 1

The solutions to these problems (on StackOverflow) suggest reformatting the hdfs and checking the entries of /etc/hosts. I tried both of them, but that didn't help.

Please let me know how to fix these errors. Thank you in advance.

---

Adding contents of core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml (same on all the machines)

core-site.xml

`<?xml version="1.0"?>` 
`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>` 
`<configuration>`

`<property>` 
        `<name>fs.default.name</name>` 
        `<value>hdfs://10.6.80.21:8020</value>` 
`</property>`

`<property>` 
        `<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>` 
        `<value>/hadoop/hdfs</value>` 
`</property>`

`</configuration>`

mapred-site.xml

`<?xml version="1.0"?>` 
`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>`

`<configuration>`

`<property>` 
`<name>mapred.job.tracker</name>` 
`<value>hdfs://10.6.80.21:8021</value>` 
`</property>`

`</configuration>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should that logs are written to *.out file but it doesnot contain much information.. Look for *.log file in /var/log/hadoop/ directories for latest logs about namenode or other demons(if you have an RPM based installation else look in $HADOOP_HOME log folder). Comming to above issue, make sure that core-site.xml in all the nodes had the namenode details specified. Similarly check mapred-site.xml across the cluster and it should contain the address of jobtracker.

Also make sure that hostnames are maintained across cluster or you can just use ip address.
hadoop.tmp.dir (location that we mention in core-site)must be created across the cluster and it should have appropriate file permission such that your hdfs user can perform read/writes.

**Core-site.xml**

```
<property>
      <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
      <value>/loation/for/temp/dir</value>
      <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://namenodehostname</value>
      <description>The name of the default file system.</description>
    </property>
```

**Mapred-site.xml**

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>jobtrackerhostname</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker
  </description>
</property>
```

If you feel that all the above properties are set in your cluster and still facing issue. Please update your complete log along with config files.

Comment: I checked the logs at the location given out when starting hadoop services (mentioned this in my question). This is $HADOOP_HOME/log location. I added the contents of my core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml to my question. It is the same across all the machines. But this didn't solve my issue.

Comment: is your namenode active ? are you able to view namenode webUI ?

Comment: When I run start-all.sh, namenode gets started (jps shows namenode as one of the process that is running). I don't have access to the UI part of the server. Do you know why the tasktracker/datanode logs don't show up in the logs folder?

Comment: I was looking for tasktracker/datanode logs on the wrong machine. I thought that master gets those logs as well. I found them on the individual slave machines. TaskTracker errors are not yet resolved. In the DataNode log, I get 

`WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid directory in dfs.data.dir: can not create directory: /hadoop/hdfs/dfs/data
2015-04-13 21:44:57,642 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: All directories in dfs.data.dir are invalid.`

Comment: In the TaskTracker log, I get

`WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: TaskTracker local dir /hadoop/hdfs/mapred/local error can not create directory: /hadoop/hdfs/mapred/local, removing from local dirs
2015-04-13 21:45:01,990 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Can not start task tracker because org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: No mapred local directories are writable`

Comment: Ok ...  Got it ... change the <property> 
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
<value>/hadoop/hdfs</value> 
</property> to a valid path .. make sure its present in the server

Comment: do you have /hadoop/hdfs in your nodes ? Also make sure that you have correct permissions to folder. Usually it should be hdfs user and hadoop group.

Comment: Yes /hadoop/hdfs is present on the master (JT, NN, SNN). Should it be present on all the slaves as well? I am using the username "ubuntu" on all the machines including the master. So the username:group is set to ubuntu:ubuntu for /hadoop/hdfs with 755 permission.

Comment: Ok .. Yes it should be present .

Comment: Thank you, that resolved the errors and now I am able to run MapReduce programs :). Thank you very much. 

Perhaps it might be helpful for others if you update your answer with these comments as well?